# Why do I need to declare android namespace only in some xml files?

Tags: android, xml

I read about XML namespaces and I got that they are used to avoid name collisions, but I would like to ask some things strange to me:

1. Why do we declare android namespace only in layouts and android manifest but not those files inside the values directory?
2. Why do we have something like this...

   ```
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_height="fill_parent">

       <EditText android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:id="@+id/eventArea"/>

   </LinearLayout>
   ```

and not like this:

```
<android:LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                      android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <android:EditText 
                     android:layout_height="fill_parent" ... />

</android:LinearLayout>
```

or like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                      layout_width="fill_parent"
                      layout_height="fill_parent">

    <EditText 
                     layout_height="fill_parent" ... />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: you mean why there is link http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android ?

Comment: I mean why sometimes there is and other times not, and why when there is just attributes are prefixed with `android:` and tag names not.

Answer (score 0):

`xmlns`  means a namespace , instead of calling `android:id` you call a `Uniform Resource Indicator(URI)` which identify the name of a resource.
for example

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

when you call the URI , it gives the linearlayout a unique idententity.

As for the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html)

> xmlns:android
>
> Defines the Android namespace. This attribute should always be set to
>   "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android".

I guess because this is a design choice by google to handle the errors at compile time and to have unique name from other android:id.

Comment: Mh, this is not what I asked :-(

Comment: what is your question then please explain it to me so i can explain

Comment: Accoding to W3CSchool (http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp) I should put `android:` also in the tag name (i.e. <android:LinearLayout>), why isn't this made in android?